# Css auto-fill/auto-fit grid is overflowing

Tags: html, css

I need a grid where the elements are between 200px and 250px wide and use auto-fit. So my approach for this would be just to use:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 250px));
```

But on small devices, the container overflows and the grid-cells are always 250px wide.

Here my full scss code:

**Container**

```
.modelContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 250px));
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

**And the element inside the grid:**

```
.defaultModel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: rgb(27, 27, 27) !important;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;

    img {
        margin: auto;
        max-width: 200px;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    p, h6 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    p {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 1rem 0;
        font-size: 1.25rem !important;
    }
    h6 {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

removing the image does not change anything.

EDIT:

**My HTML**

```
<div className="modelContainer">
        <div className="defaultModel">
            <div className="imageContainer">
                <img src={image}/>
            </div>
            
            <p>Title 1</p>
            <h6>1.199,99 €</h6>
        </div>
        <div className="defaultModel">
            <div className="imageContainer">
                <img src={image}/>
            </div>
            
            <p>Title 2</p>
            <h6>1.199,99 €</h6>
        </div>
        <div className="defaultModel">
            <div className="imageContainer">
                <img src={image}/>
            </div>
            
            <p>Title 3</p>
            <h6>1.199,99 €</h6>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some HTML so we don't have hard times debugging?

Comment: yes, updated the question

Comment: created a codepen: https://codepen.io/skazzy_ch/pen/KKqZbNG?editors=1100 I don't get your problem...

Comment: in cour codepen its not overflowing like on my site, but still the cards are always 250 px wide. But I wonder why it does not overflow there

Comment: They change their size when the viewport is smaller than 250px

Comment: is there a way to make them go to 200px for example when I have 420px space in the container so that they then fit in one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
.modelContainer {
  ...
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
}
```

but then you'll have to set a `max-with` to the parent container.

If you want to display only 3 containers you can use this:

```css
.modelContainer {
    margin: 0 auto; /* new */
    max-width: calc(3 * 250px + 4rem); /* new */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    justify-content: center;
}
.defaultModel {
  max-width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: rgb(27, 27, 27) !important;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;

    img {
        margin: auto;
        max-width: 200px;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    p, h6 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    p {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 1rem 0;
        font-size: 1.25rem !important;
    }
    h6 {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="modelContainer">
  <div class="defaultModel">
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <img src={image}/>
    </div>
    <p>Title 1</p>
    <h6>1.199,99 €</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="defaultModel">
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <img src={image}/>
    </div>
    <p>Title 2</p>
    <h6>1.199,99 €</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="defaultModel">
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <img src={image}/>
    </div>
    <p>Title 3</p>
    <h6>1.199,99 €</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried this too, but this is not the behaviour I need, because I want to justify the content to the center but with this approach their are 3 equal grid-cells and justify-content center does not work then.

Comment: edited my answer for 3 containers

Comment: thank you, this is basically what I need. The behaviour for the case where there is only one column is a bit strange but I think this should be fixable

Answer (score 0):

I solved the overflow on small screens as follows.

```
    .grid--auto-columns {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
     }

    @media (min-width: 40em) {
      .grid--auto-columns {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
      }
    }
```